# Cannot lock mongochef to launcher on ubuntu 17.04 server

Tags: 17.04

I can go to the directory of the `mongochef` studio and into the bin folder, and from there run the program with:

```
bin ./studio-3t.sh
```

On the left system tray, I right click on the icon and click <kbd>Lock to launcher</kbd> but nothing happens.

I did the same for intellij idea and it worked.

I did the same for the same program in another instance of Ubuntu.

Now in the same Ubuntu, 17.04, I can't do it.

Also I have this problem:

[Icons In System Settings are Missing Ubuntu Server 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925671/icons-in-system-settings-are-missing-ubuntu-server-17-04)

Can it be related? Should I reinstall the desktop? Will I lose all my icons if I do?

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and I fix it as blew:

(1) enter the directory [~/.local/share/applications]

(2) delete the  *robot3.desktop

(3) open the robot3 and lock it to the launcher again.