# Touchpad not disabled on 17.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.04

I did those steps

https://askubuntu.com/a/904677/694849

then i could see option of disabling touchpad and i disabled it.

[touchpad disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbwHT.png)

then rstarted but still i can use touchpad.

Why?

i have also those problems

[Cannot lock mongochef to launcher on ubuntu 17.04 server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926111/cannot-lock-mongochef-to-launcher-on-ubuntu-17-04-server)

[Icons In System Settings are Missing Ubuntu Server 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925671/icons-in-system-settings-are-missing-ubuntu-server-17-04)

can they be related

Answer (score 1):

One method to disable the touchpad, would be to write a simple script and run that script at startup.  To do this, you will need to know the name of your touchpad.  Open a terminal and run the command

`xinput -list`

The output on my computer is

```
chick@dad:~$ xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M315/M235                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys
```

and the name of my touchpad is `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad`

The touchpad can be diabled by `xinput --disable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'`, and re-enabled by `xinput --enable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'`

A simple script to run this command, for example

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput --disable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
```

can now be written, and executed at startup or login
.  Good instructions on how to do that can be found at [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)